# System call to shut down or 'power cycle' ethernet card on windows?

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to write a python script that makes a series of system calls in order to rapidly change IP addresses. Part of the string of events that must happen is going into network connections in the ctrl panel and clicking the local area connection off and then clicking it back on. It seems that there must a system call that would accomplish this task. What is it? Or might there be a python specific command?

Comment: Welcome to SO! [www.whathaveyoutried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['ipconfig', '/renew'])
```

Using [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) (Python) and [`ipconfig`](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/a/ipconfig.htm) (Windows). Though you'll only get a different IP address if your DHCP server chooses to dish one out to you, contact your system administrator.